# How to create telegram poll using google sheet in less time

Tags: google-sheets, telegram

I have questions and options in a google sheet that I wanted to convert in telegram poll. Is there any way to do this task without manual method

Answer (score 0):

You could build a small bot that uses the Google Sheet's API to read each question and its answers.

From there, and for each question you can utilise the Telegram bot to send each question as a message to a Telegram channel where you can have people participate.

As long as the Google Sheet document is in a format which you can parse into questions and answers then this approach should work perfectly.

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#poll

This link details the parameters and config for a Telegram poll request.